# How to get details of service listening on a port in Go

Tags: go, networking

I'm working on a project that needs to communicate with either a service listening in localhost with port 55555 or with the docker container of that service based on some conditions. If the service is already listening on port 55555, then I have to communicate with that and skip starting its docker container.

How do I know which service is listening on port 55555?. Is there any workaround in Go to do this??

Comment: You can try connecting to port 55555 and see if the connection succeeds? If it succeeds, you can talk to the service to verify it's what you expect - but this depends on the nature of the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
command := "lsof -i:55555"
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", command)
bytes,err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
     log.Println(err)
}
resp := string(bytes)
log.Println(resp)
```

you can exec shell by golang code